# React: How to animate the change of the component rendered?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation

I change the component that is rendered through a time interval.

I would like to be able to add an animation every time that change happens. What is the best way to go about it?

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { currentComponent: 1,
    numberOfComponents: 2}
}

componentWillMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
       if(this.state.currentComponent === 2) {
           this.setState({currentComponent: 1})
       } else {
           this.setState({currentComponent: this.state.currentComponent + 1})
       }
    }, 5000)
}

render(){

    let currentComponent = null;

    if(this.state.currentComponent === 1) {
        currentComponent = <ComponentOne/>;

    } else {
        currentComponent = <ComponentTwo/>;
    }

    return(
        currentComponent
    )
}
```

EDIT:

Also when trying to use 'react-addons-css-transition-group'
I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: The easiest in my opinion is using CSS3 transitions. You give your elements a class based on your state, which changes your element's styling. You can transition this styling using the CSS3 transitions (or CSS3 animations).

Answer (score 1):

You can do with ReactCSSTransitionGroup like provided in this [section](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html)

Your css:

```
.example-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
}

.example-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}

.example-leave.example-leave-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
}
```

Will look like this:

```
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';



class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { currentComponent: 1,
    numberOfComponents: 2}
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
       if(this.state.currentComponent === 2) {
           this.setState({currentComponent: 1})
       } else {
           this.setState({currentComponent: this.state.currentComponent + 1})
       }
    }, 5000)
  }

  render(){

    let currentComponent = null;

    if(this.state.currentComponent === 1) {
        currentComponent = <ComponentOne/>;

    } else {
        currentComponent = <ComponentTwo/>;
    }

    return(
        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
          transitionName="example"
           transitionEnterTimeout={500}
          transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
          {currentComponent}
        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>

    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I attempted but every time I import that library. I keep getting the following error:

       Uncaught TypeError: React.PropTypes.shape is not a function

Comment: This error is probably somewhere else...  Where do you have Protypes definitions in you app?

Comment: I actually get it from the library. I added the error screenshot on my post.

Comment: Which versions of react and react-transitions are you using?

Comment: react@15.4.1
react-addons-css-transition-group@15.0.2

Comment: I don't know... could you send me a repo so I run it here?