# How do I resolve "React.PropTypes.shape is not a function"?

Tags: reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup, react-proptypes

There is literally one Google result for the query "React.PropTypes.shape is not a function".  It is [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41472769/react-how-to-animate-the-change-of-the-component-rendered), that does not address this error, though it has the same ostensible cause as it caused by the same React add-on.

I get this error when using `ReactTransitionGroup` after installing `'react-addons-css-transition-group'`.

I am using the latest `React` and `'react-addons-css-transition-group'` versions: `^15.4.2`, for each.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
          transitionName="example"
          transitionAppear={true}
          transitionAppearTimeout={500}
          transitionEnter={true}
          transitionLeave={false}>
          <div key="some unique ass key just in case this matters">Test</div>
          <strong>Welcome to StockBase.com!</strong> StockBase brings you Portfolio News in One Place.
          </div>
        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

```

This doesn't seem to be a bug on my end, as the error is saying that a `react` function, `React.PropTypes.shape` does not exist.  This function was released ages ago, so I'm pretty perplexed.  I copied the [CSS classes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#high-level-api-reactcsstransitiongroup) verbatim, though I don't see how those matter

Answer (score 0):

Installing prop-types as a dependency and not a devDependency fixed this for me.